# How to make gen fill added objects blend to the original image better?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows, composition, artificial-intelligence

I extended a Katy Perry album cover using Photoshop's generative fill and Stable Diffusion, now the image looks like this:

[image]

It looks OK, but I'm sure there are some techniques for how to make the image look better. (e.g make the gummy bears and the candy canes blend better, fix something with the lighting or the shadows, etc)

I'm a complete beginner at Photoshop. Can you tell me some things that I should learn, so that I can make the image look better?